# Child theme not inheriting certain scripts and styles

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this theme:https://dessign.net/sold-responsive-woocommerce-free/
and I have created a child theme. I set it up by adding

```
    function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() .  
    /style.css' );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

but certain things are not  being applied like the sticky headeror mobile menu. Is there anything else I need to include?

Answer (score 1):

Your child theme's stylesheet will usually be loaded automatically. If it is not, you will need to enqueue it as well. Setting 'parent-style' as a dependency will ensure that the child theme stylesheet loads after it. See here a more detailed discussion :

```
<?php
function theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style';

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style )
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: and check header.php. it's not the best practice but sometimes the .js and .css are 'inline' in this block.

Comment: Thank you, now the sticky header is also being applied, but the mobile menu is still not. I checked header.php but the js and css is not included inline...